# What's the maximum size limit of a Hosted FeatureLayer

Tags: arcgis-portal, arcgis-survey123, hosted-feature-layer

I am looking at designing some surveys and noted that Survey123 uses Hosted FeatureLayers, rather than a Hosted FeatureService.  I recall there being a limit on the size of these layers (2GB?) but cannot find any information in the area.  As we are going to be proucing large amounts of data, coupled to lots of photos, I want to mitigate any risk to the project.

Is there a specific size limit to a Hosted FeatureLayer stored on the ArcGIS Data Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above was wrong: you can only load individual files to a Hosted Feature Layer of 2GB.  The layers themselves can be much larger.